# Capturing image preview as like as on the screen with AVFoundation

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I set the `AVCaptureSession` preset PhotoPreset

```
self.session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto;
```

and then adding a new layer into my view with

```
 AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:self.session];
[previewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
CALayer *rootLayer = [self.view layer];
[rootLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[previewLayer setFrame:[rootLayer bounds]];
[rootLayer addSublayer:previewLayer];
```

So far so good, However when I want to capture an image, I use the code below

```
 AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = [self.stillImageOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

[self.stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
 {

     [self.session stopRunning];

     NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
     UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData ];

     self.imageView.image = image; //IMAGEVIEW IS WITH THE BOUNDS OF SELF.VIEW
     image = nil;


 }];
```

Capturing an image is fine however, the captured image is different comparing to `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` showing on the screen. What I really want to do is to show captured as like as appearing on `AVCapturePreviewLayer` layer. How can I achieve this? How should I resize and crop the captured image with respect to the bounds of `self.view`?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, have you find a solution or something that might lead us to a solution? (:

Thanks.

Comment: WWDC 2011 Session 419 solved all of my questions. They have sample codes as well to solve your problem :)

Comment: @kkocabiyik, while I appreciate the reference, it'd be nice if you could elaborate more when you solve your own questions on here. People will continue to find your unanswered question via google or searching SO and a comment saying an hour long video solved your questions doesn't exactly help others. At the very least a timestamp would help.

Comment: If you could elaborate a bit that would be helpful. I am also needing to solve this problem.

Answer (score -1):

i am not sure this will help you or not but as you talking about cropping images so i crop image in ImagePickerView with following code I am not sure this will help you or not

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    self.lastChosenMediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    if ([lastChosenMediaType isEqual:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
        UIImage *chosenImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
        UIImage *shrunkenImage = shrinkImage(chosenImage, imageFrame.size);
        self.imagee = shrunkenImage;
        selectImage.image = imagee;

    }     [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {    
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

// function for cropping images you can do some changes in parameter as per your requirements  
static UIImage *shrinkImage(UIImage *original, CGSize size) {
    CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, size.width * scale,
                                                 size.height * scale, 8, 0, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    CGContextDrawImage(context,
                       CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width * scale, size.height * scale),
                       original.CGImage);
    CGImageRef shrunken = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIImage *final = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:shrunken];

    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGImageRelease(shrunken);   

    return final;
}
```

Comment: It is actually not about cropping and resizing. Since AVFoundation returns me an image that is with originial image size, i need to crop and resize it according to the image that is appearing on the screen with AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer while capturing an image.

Comment: best of luck for this i am sure you will find some way for it :)